# Convert Json sub-array to Flutter List

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been struggling with this for sometime and cannot get the output I expect, I've gotten as far as I can but hit a deadend.

I have a remote json source coming in and I've managed to map all but one key as it is several children which I need to make into a Flutter List.

Json:

```
{
    "id": "4897b00f-a766-4f63-9ef5-b45da222e7ae",
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "tradingName": null,
    "short": "JOEBL",
    "website": "http://",
    "status": "Active",
    "balance": {
        "data": {
            "outstanding": "529.52",
            "overdue": "1505.47"
        }
    },
    "counts": {
        "data": {
            "icpCount": 2,
            "siteCount": 0
        }
    },
    "basicConsumption": {
        "data": [
            {
                "month": "Jun",
                "units": 0
            },
            {
                "month": "Jul",
                "units": 466
            },
            {
                "month": "Aug",
                "units": 0
            },
            {
                "month": "Sep",
                "units": 868
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to return this as an *Account* class which I've accomplished in this portion of a Future:

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body)['data'];

account = Account.fromJson(data);

return account;
```

but I cannot have it also have the *basicConsumption*.

Here are my two models:

```
class Account {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String trading;
  final String short;
  final String website;
  final AccountBalance balance;
  final AccountCount counter;
  final List<Consumption> consumption;
  bool selected = false;

  Account({@required this.id, @required this.name, this.trading, this.short, this.website, this.balance, this.counter, this.consumption});

  factory Account.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Account(
    id: json['id'],
    name: json['name'],
    trading: json['tradingName'] == null ? '' : json['tradingName'],
    short: json['short'],
    website: json['website'],
    balance: json.containsKey("balance") ? AccountBalance.fromJson(json["balance"]['data']) : AccountBalance(outstanding: '-', overdue: '-'),
    counter: json.containsKey("counts") ? AccountCount.fromJson(json["counts"]['data']) : AccountCount(icps: 0, sites: 0),
    consumption: json.containsKey("basicConsumption") ? List<Consumption>.fromJson(json["basicConsumption"]['data'] as Iterable) : null,
  );
}

  class Consumption {
      String month;
      int units;

  Consumption({
    this.month,
    this.units,
  });

  Consumption.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Consumption(
    month: json["month"] == null ? null : json["month"],
    units: json["units"] == null ? null : json["units"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "month": month == null ? null : month,
    "units": units == null ? null : units,
  };
}
```

I just get the error **The class 'List' doesn't have a constructor named 'fromJson'.**

I'm not sure how to get this to work, and how to get from where I am to an output like this:

```
final List<Consumption> data = [
    Consumption(
      month: "Feb",
      units: 250,
    ),
    Consumption(
      month: "Feb",
      units: 300,
    ),
];
```

Really would appreciate some help on this one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List does not have the constructor `fromJson` but it does have the constructor `from`.

```
consumption: json.containsKey("basicConsumption") ? List<Consumption>.from(json["basicConsumption"]['data'].map((model)=> Consumption.fromJson(model))) : null
```

Comment: This is actually the method I went with at the end of yesterday and it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:_samples3/json/data_x_1.dart';

typedef JMap = Map<String, dynamic>;

class Account {
  late final String id, name, trading, short, website;
  late final AccountBalance balance;
  late final AccountCount counter;
  late final List<Consumption>? consumption;
  bool selected = false;

  Account.fromJson(JMap data) {
    id = data['id'];
    name = data['name'];
    trading = data['tradingName'] ?? '';
    short = data['short'];
    website = data['website'];
    balance = AccountBalance.fromJson(data['balance']?['data']);
    counter = AccountCount.fromJson(data['counts']?['data']);

    List? _tmp = data['basicConsumption']?['data'];
    consumption = _tmp == null 
      ? null
      : List.generate(_tmp.length, (i) => Consumption.fromJson(_tmp[i]));
  }
}

class AccountBalance {
  late final double? outstanding, overdue;

  AccountBalance.fromJson(JMap? data) {
    outstanding = double.tryParse(data?['outstanding'] ?? '');
    overdue = double.tryParse(data?['overdue'] ?? '');
  }
}

class AccountCount {
  late final int? icpCount, siteCount;

  AccountCount.fromJson(JMap? data) {
    icpCount = data?['icpCount'];
    siteCount =data?['siteCount'];
  }
}

class Consumption {
  late final String? month;
  late final int? units;
  
  Consumption.fromJson(JMap? data) {
    month = data?['month'];
    units = data?['units'];
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var data = jsonDecode(data_x_raw);
  var account = Account.fromJson(data);

  print(account);
}
```

Result:

```
Instance of 'Account'
```